# Proving $\lim(\frac{n}{n+1})^2 = 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to prove the following statement

$$\lim(\frac{n}{n+1})^2 = 1.$$

However, I am stuck in formulating the comparison needed to choose N.
We know
\begin{align}
\left|\left(\frac{n}{n + 1}\right)^2 -1\right|
& = \left|\frac{n^2}{n^2 + 2n + 1} - 1\right|
= \left|\frac{n^2 - n^2 - 2n - 1}{n^2 + 2n + 1}\right| \\
& = \left|\frac{-2n -1}{n^2 + 2n + 1}\right|
= \frac{2n +1}{n^2 + 2n + 1}
< \frac{2}{n}
< \epsilon.
\end{align}

How do we reach the conclusion that $\frac{2n +1}{n^2 + 2n + 1} < \frac{2}{n}$. Please help me with a general method that I could apply to similar problems

Comment: You can just rearrange the inequality to convince you that it works: $\frac{2n + 1}{n^2 + 2n + 1} < \frac{2}{n}$ is equivalent to $2n^2 + n < 2n^2 + 4n + 2$. Collecting like terms we get $0 < + 3n + 2$, which is true for $n > 0$.

Comment: Thank you. But How would you have guessed it in the first place?

Comment: Note that $\frac{2n+1}{n^2+2n+1} = \frac{2(n+1/2)}{(n+1)^2}$. You should always first look at the highest degree because these determine the growth rate. Choosing $\frac{2}{n}$ then is more or less arbitrary.

Comment: As an aside, your limit is ambiguous.  From context, you clearly mean the limit *as $n$ approaches infinity* however this should still be made explicitly clear by instead using $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$

Answer (score 2):

**Note** it is easier to see that:

$$\frac{2n +1}{n^2 + 2n + 1}< \frac{2n+n}{n^2} =\frac{3}{n}$$

Usually, your goal is to replace the "ugly" fraction $\frac{2n +1}{n^2 + 2n + 1}$ by something nicer. The rule of thumb is: make the denominator larger, denominator smaller, but try to keep the "dominating" terms.